# Angular UI-Router Overwrite Resolve in Child States

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm running into the issue, that I have the same resolve function in parent & child states - and depending on the child state, i would like to have it return a different value.
Somehow, instead of overwriting the implementation for it, it simply just takes the behavior from the parent state.

```
.state('wines', {
    url: '/wines',
    templateUrl: 'partials/products/index',
    controller: 'cwProductsController',
    resolve: {
      merchandiseView: function() {
        return "featured";
      }
    }
  }).state('wines.featured', {
    url: "/featured",
    templateUrl: 'partials/products/index',
    controller: 'cwProductsController',
    resolve: {
      merchandiseView: function() {
        return "featured";
      }
    }
  }).state('wines.curatorsChoice', {
    url: "/curators-choice",
    templateUrl: 'partials/products/index',
    controller: 'cwProductsController',
    resolve: {
      merchandiseView: function() {
        return "curators-choice";
      }
    }
  }).state('wines.stillAvailable', {
    url: "/still-available",
    templateUrl: 'partials/products/index',
    controller: 'cwProductsController',
    resolve: {
      merchandiseView: function() {
        return "still-available";
      }
    }

  });
```

Here, it always keeps on returning "featured", even when visiting  *wines/still-available*, where I expect merchandiseView to be "still-available".

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('clubwApp').controller('cwProductsController', [
  '$scope', 'cwProduct', '$stateParams', 'merchandiseView', function($scope, cwProduct, $stateParams, merchandiseView) {
    console.log(merchandiseView);
    $scope.wines = cwProduct.available();
    return $scope.merchandiseView = angular.copy(merchandiseView);
  }
]);
```

Is there a way, how i can overwrite this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Attach you specific data to the `data` state property instead of the `resolve`.
- At controller initialization time read `$state.current.data` from the `$state` injectable.

Comment: This, in addition with declaring another ui-view in my Views seemed to work out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently an issue (up until 0.2.15). 
Here is a hacky solution to the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/j1wCThlv1uczlX7d5cdg?p=preview
the `resolve: {test: {this.data.someObject}}`